# Images in HTML [JAVASCRIPT] to change after a number of seconds

Tags: javascript, html, function, timer, assets

This code I have works to an extent; It changes but only very quickly, I would like it to change after 3 seconds or so, but I can't find out how. Thanks in advance!

CODE:

```
<img id = "theImage" src="red.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:250px;height:500px;" align = left>

<script>
var sequence = ["red.jpg", "red&amber.jpg", "green.jpg", "amber.jpg"];
var place = 0;

setInterval(change_light,1);
function change_light() {
  place += 1;
  if (place > sequence.length -1) {
    place = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('theImage').src = sequence[place];
}
```

Comment: Mark correct answer please if you decided a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use milliseconds in setInterval period. Try this please. I also simplified your conditions:

```
var sequence = ["red.jpg", "red&amber.jpg", "green.jpg", "amber.jpg"];
var place = 0;
var frameInterval = 1000; // milliseconds

setInterval(change_light, frameInterval);
function change_light() {
  place++;
  place = place % sequence.length;
  document.getElementById('theImage').src = sequence[place];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Always looking to improve :)

Comment: Can I ask what "place = place % sequence.length"s function could be defined as? I'm assuming it would just be the same as before, just without the if? For some reason this has confused me a little.. could you define its use please? I like to be able to understand it thoroughly :)

Comment: Sure! It's a remainder operator which returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand. More about it you can find here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder

Answer (score 0):

setInterval expects you to pass number of milliseconds (not seconds)

Use it like this: `setInterval(change_light,3000);`

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, you did everything right! just a tiny change:
the function **setInterval(change_light,3000);** should receive it's time in milliseconds and not in seconds.

and also I would like to suggest to add some return value to setInterval then you will be able to clear this timer if want using:

```
clearInterval(change_light_id);
```

and here is your fixed code:

```
<img id = "theImage" src="red.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:250px;height:500px;" align = left>

<script>
var sequence = ["red.jpg", "red&amber.jpg", "green.jpg", "amber.jpg"];
var place = 0;

change_light_id = setInterval(change_light,3000);

function change_light() {
  console.log(1);
  place += 1;
  if (place > sequence.length -1) {
    place = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('theImage').src = sequence[place];
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!